# SqlBulkCopy Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy

I have a `DataSet` populated from Excel Sheet. I wanted to use SQLBulk Copy to Insert Records in `Lead_Hdr` table where `LeadId` is PK.

I am having following error while executing the code below:

> The given ColumnMapping does not match up with any column in the
>   source or destination

```
string ConStr=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ToString();

using (SqlBulkCopy s = new SqlBulkCopy(ConStr,SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
{
    if (MySql.State==ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        MySql.Open();
    }

    s.DestinationTableName = "PCRM_Lead_Hdr";
    s.NotifyAfter = 10000;

    #region Comment
    s.ColumnMappings.Clear();

    #region ColumnMapping
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("ClientID", "ClientID");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("LeadID", "LeadID");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Company_Name", "Company_Name");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Website", "Website");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("EmployeeCount", "EmployeeCount");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Revenue", "Revenue");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Address", "Address");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");

    s.ColumnMappings.Add("State", "State");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("ZipCode", "ZipCode");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("CountryId", "CountryId");

    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Phone", "Phone");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Fax", "Fax");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("TimeZone", "TimeZone");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("SicNo", "SicNo");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("SicDesc", "SicDesc");

    s.ColumnMappings.Add("SourceID", "SourceID");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("ResearchAnalysis", "ResearchAnalysis");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("BasketID", "BasketID");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("PipeLineStatusId", "PipeLineStatusId");

    s.ColumnMappings.Add("SurveyId", "SurveyId");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("NextCallDate", "NextCallDate");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("CurrentRecStatus", "CurrentRecStatus");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("AssignedUserId", "AssignedUserId");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("AssignedDate", "AssignedDate");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("ToValueAmt", "ToValueAmt");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Remove", "Remove");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Release", "Release");

    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Insert_Date", "Insert_Date");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Insert_By", "Insert_By");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Updated_Date", "Updated_Date");
    s.ColumnMappings.Add("Updated_By", "Updated_By");

    #endregion
    #endregion

    s.WriteToServer(sourceTable);

    s.Close();

    MySql.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well, is it right? Do the column names exist on both sides?

To be honest, I've never bothered with mappings. I like to keep things simple - I tend to have a staging table that looks like the input on the server, then I `SqlBulkCopy` into the staging table, and finally run a stored procedure to move the table from the staging table into the actual table; advantages:

- no issues with live data corruption if the import fails at any point
- I can put a transaction just around the SPROC
- I can have the bcp work without logging, safe in the knowledge that the SPROC will be logged
- it is simple ;-p (no messing with mappings)

As a final thought - if you are dealing with bulk data, you can get better throughput using `IDataReader` (since this is a streaming API, where-as `DataTable` is a buffered API). For example, I tend to hook CSV imports up using [CsvReader](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CsvReader.aspx) as the source for a SqlBulkCopy. Alternatively, I have written shims around `XmlReader` to present each first-level element as a row in an `IDataReader` - very fast.

Comment: Well I am new to this "Staging" Term Can You please Explain it a bit

Comment: A staging table is a table that you dump your data into.  Often, it doesn't have an index so that writing is faster.  Dump into a staging table, manipulate data, and write from staging to your production tables using a stored procedure (wrap it in a transaction to protect from corruption).

Comment: Remember that staging table data is transient, so clear it out before you put data in, and don't use it to retrieve data except to transform it to output to another set of tables.  Also, remember that staged data tends to be less normal than your "real" data.

Answer (score 40):

I've encountered the same problem while copying data from access to SQLSERVER 2005 and i found that the column mappings are case sensitive on both data sources regardless of the databases sensitivity.

Comment: I had the same issue, there is an active bug for it: 
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/94135/sqlbulkcopy-column-mappings-case-sensitivity

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2008 R2. And this is still a problem too. So becareful ppl, column is still case sensitive in Sql 2008 apparently (in the year 2013). I've also updated my sql server 2008 R2 to latest service pack etc.

Comment: As great as Marc's feedback is, this should be the accepted answer because case sensitivity is probably the most common cause of this error (see all the stackoverflow questions related to SqlBulkCopy class). The issue is NOT with any version of SQL Server because SQL Server doesn't care about column case, its the SqlBulkCopy .NET class that is enforcing case sensitivity and this class should have a property to disable case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Marc would be my recomendation (on using staging table). This ensures that if your source doesn't change, you'll have fewer issues importing in the future.

However, in my experience, you can check the following issues:

Column names match in source and table
That the column types match

If you think you did this and still no success. You can try the following.

1 - Allow nulls in all columns in your table
2 - comment out all column mappings
3 - rerun adding one column at a time until you find where your issue is

That should bring out the bug

Answer (score 2):

One of the reason is that :SqlBukCOpy is case sensitive . Follow steps:

1. In that Case first you have to find your column in Source Table by
   using "Contain" method in C#.
2. Once your Destination column matched with source column get index of
   that column and give its column name in SqlBukCOpy .

For Example:`

```
//Get Column from Source table 
  string sourceTableQuery = "Select top 1 * from sourceTable";
   DataTable dtSource=SQLHelper.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(transaction, CommandType.Text, sourceTableQuery).Tables[0];// i use sql helper for executing query you can use corde sw

 for (int i = 0; i < destinationTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {    //check if destination Column Exists in Source table
                            if (dtSource.Columns.Contains(destinationTable.Columns[i].ToString()))//contain method is not case sensitive
                            {
                                int sourceColumnIndex = dtSource.Columns.IndexOf(destinationTable.Columns[i].ToString());//Once column matched get its index
                                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dtSource.Columns[sourceColumnIndex].ToString(), dtSource.Columns[sourceColumnIndex].ToString());//give coluns name of source table rather then destination table so that it would avoid case sensitivity
                            }

                        }
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(destinationTable);
                        bulkCopy.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the staging idea, however here is my approach to handling the case sensitive nature. Happy to be critiqued on my linq

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn_str))
{
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = string.Format("[{0}].[{1}].[{2}]", targetDatabase, targetSchema, targetTable);
            var targetColumsAvailable = GetSchema(conn_str, targetTable).ToArray();
            foreach (var column in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (targetColumsAvailable.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).Contains(column.ToString().ToUpper()))
                {
                    var tc = targetColumsAvailable.Single(x => String.Equals(x, column.ToString(), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(column.ToString(), tc);
                }
            }

            // Write from the source to the destination.
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            bulkCopy.Close();
        }
}
```

and the helper method

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetSchema(string connectionString, string tableName)
        {



   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "sp_Columns";
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add("@table_name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 384).Value = tableName;

            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return (string)reader["column_name"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is that the columns in the table and the columns in the input must at least match. You can have more columns in the table and the input will still load. If you have less you'll receive the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thought a long time about answering...
Even if column names are case equally, if the data type differs
you get the same error. So check column names and their data type.

P.S.: staging tables are definitive the way to import.